# How can I find all files that do NOT contain a text string?

Tags: grep, find, recursive

What **concise** command can I use to find all files that do NOT contain a text string?

I tried this (using -v to invert grep's parameters) with no luck:

```
find . -exec grep -v -l shared.php {} \;
```

Someone said this would work:

```
find . ! -exec grep -l shared.php {} \;
```

But it does not seem to work for me.

[This page](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/13861-search-files-dont-contain-string.html) has this example:

```
find ./logs -size +1c  > t._tmp
while read filename
do
     grep -q "Process Complete" $filename
     if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
             echo $filename
     fi
done < t._tmp
rm -f t_tmp
```

But that's cumbersome and not at all concise.

ps: I know that `grep -L *` will do this, but how can I use the find command in combination with grep to excluded files is what I really want to know.

pss: Also I'm not sure how to have grep include subdirectories with the `grep -L *` syntax, but I still want to know how to use it with `find` :)

Comment: The first command you wrote worked fine on my computer. What version of find are you using? And since we're at it, maybe specify which unix you're running..

Comment: @rahmu, this command _almost always_ does not work as you expect. You probably have had a very specific case. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339619/is-grep-v-l-equivalent-to-grep-l?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -H -c 'shared.php' | grep 0$ | cut -d':' -f1
```

OR

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H -c 'shared.php' {} \; | grep 0$ | cut -d':' -f1
```

Here we are calculating number of matching lines(using `-c`) in a file if the count is 0 then its the required file, so we cut the first column i.e. filename from the output.

Comment: This is awfully complicated. See [Kevin's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26837).

Comment: @Gilles yes I agree with you. I have +1 his answer.

Comment: This is not only "awfully complicated" but _wrong_ as it would also list all files that contain a multiple of 10 lines matching the pattern. Even if that `grep` was fixed this would still assume no file names containing `:` or _newline_ characters...

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks for mentioning! Still, unless you use a lot of copy-paste code, the solution above is a rly nice gimmick.

Comment: @Ufos - I really don't get your comment... This is _wrong_. Anyway, feel free to use it if it looks like a "really nice gimmick" to you...

Comment: The second command of the pipe `grep 0$` should be `grep :0$` otherwise a count of 10,20,100,... will pass the grep and we are only looking for counters with 0.

Answer (score 88):

Your find should work if you change `-v -l` (files that have any line not matching) to `-L` (files with no lines matching), but you could also use `grep`'s recursive (`-r`) option:

```
grep -rL shared.php .
```

Comment: which find should work?

Comment: @Kevin - sorry, `find . -exec grep -v -l shared.php {} \;` (and all the other variants I tried) is not working for me. I'm on OS X but I don't think that should matter. I gave you a +1 because I had forgotten about the `-r` option.

Comment: @cwd i know this is old but i want to leave this here for future readers: the fact that you're on OS X does make a difference.  Mac OSX uses FreeBSD commands.  Most people here assume Linux (GNU) style commands.  They have different arguments, different ways of handling details.

Comment: As of 2016 OSX does appear to support `-L`

Comment: @kevin I said it does, not that it doesn't. :) not that anyone explicitly said it didn't, but the comments were confusing (and I've certainly run into other OS X / BSD vs GNU issues).

Comment: @DavidMoles oh wow, I must have misread that half a dozen times.

Comment: By far the best, fastest and most concise answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

> I know that `grep -L *` will do this, but how can I use the `find` command
>   in combination with `grep` to exclude files is what I really want to
>   know

You could use `find` and `grep` like this:

```
find . -type f ! -exec grep -q 'PATTERN' {} \; -print
```

Here `-print` is executed only if the previous expression: `! -exec ... {}` evaluates as `true`.
So for each file found, `grep -q 'PATTERN'` is `exec`uted, if the result is `false` then  the entire expression `! -exec grep -q 'PATTERN'` evaluates as `true` and the file name is `print`ed.

Comment: That one has the benefit of being standard and portable.

Comment: There's a difference with GNU's `grep -L` though in that it will also include the non-readable files in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You find not matching result by option -L

```
grep -iL shared.php .
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a command like

```
find . -type f -execdir grep -q -v shared.php {} \; -print
```

The option `-q` makes `grep` quit and after using `-execdir` you need `-print` to print found files.

Comment: see [Is 'grep -v -l' equivalent to 'grep -L'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/339619)