# Is 'grep -v -l' equivalent to 'grep -L'?

Tags: grep

Every once in a while there's an answer (or a comment) that suggests using `grep`'s `-v` and `-l` switches together instead of the `-L` (especially when the latter isn't available). The authors seem to believe they are equivalent.

So, are they interchangeable? IOW, does `grep -v -l` produce the same result as `grep -L`?

Answer (score 12):

No, they're not equivalent and as such the results will *almost always*<sup>1</sup> be different.
Let's see what each of those switches does:

```
‘-L’
‘--files-without-match’
     Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file
     from which no output would normally have been printed.
```

This should be simple:
`grep -L 'pattern' ./*`
prints the name of each file that does not contain any line matching `'pattern'`.

```
‘-v’
‘--invert-match’
     Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

This should be very simple too:
`grep -v 'pattern' ./*`
prints all lines not matching `'pattern'` from each file.

```
‘-l’
‘--files-with-matches’
     Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file
     from which output would normally have been printed.
```

Again, simple:
`grep -l 'pattern' ./*`
prints the name of each file that contains at least one line matching `'pattern'`.

Now, what happens when combining `-v` and `-l` ? It's not much different from `grep -l`, except that it selects the non-matching lines hence
`grep -vl 'pattern' ./*`
prints the name of each file that contains at least one line not matching `'pattern'`.

---

So, note the difference:

`grep -L` prints the file name *only if there is no line matching* `'pattern'`
`grep -vl` prints the file name *only if there is at least one line not matching* `'pattern'`

---

<sup>1:</sup>
based on the above, it's easy to see when could these two commands produce the same output:
-either when the file is not empty and *all* lines match the pattern - in which case there will be no output
-or when the file is not empty and *no* line matches the pattern - in which case it will be listed

---

Moral of the story: never use `grep -vl` to emulate `grep -L`.
If your `grep` does not support `-L`, [*this is the proper way to emulate it*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339764).

Comment: These are not the only cases where the two commands produce the same output. It can happen by coincidence. A useful case is that they are equivalent when all files contain exactly one line.

Comment: It is enough for *each* matching file to have only matching lines or only non-matching lines, they don't have to *all* fall under the same case. Also, in the “only matching lines” case, there has to be at least one line.

Answer (score 4):

As an extra note, on systems whose `grep` doesn't support the `-L` option (a GNU extension), using `-vl` wouldn't help as @don_crissti has shown, you'd need to resort to a shell loop. The equivalent of

```
grep -L pattern ./*
```

would be:

```
for file in ./*; do
  {
     grep -q pattern || printf '%s\n' "$file"
  } < "$file"
done
```

You'll notice that the redirection is done on the whole `{...}` instead of just `grep` as we don't want the name of the file to be printed if it can't be opened.

For the equivalent of `grep -ZL pattern ./*` (which you need if you want to be able to post-process that output reliably), replace `%s\n` with `%s\0` above.

For the equivalent of GNU's `grep -rL pattern .`, you can do:

```
find . -type f ! -exec grep -q pattern {} \; -print
```

Though it would also print the names of the files that are not readable (the `-readable` `find` predicate could be used, but it's also a GNU extension, so chances are that if your `grep` doesn't support `-L`, your `find` won't support `-readable` either).

With `zsh`:

```
for f (./**/*(DN.)) {{grep -q pattern || print -r $f}<$f}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a formula to represent each combination of options.

- There is a file with  `n` lines
- The text in line  `i` is represented as  `L(i)`
- `match(L(i))`  means  `L(i)` matches a search pattern

### `-l`: A file with at least one matching line

[image: -l]

### `-L`: A file without any matches

[image: -L]

### `-vl`: A file with at least one non-matching line

[image: -vl]

### `-vL`: An empty file or a file where every line matches

[image: -vL]